# On Servlet the values are null when Post method is used but when Get method is used then its fine

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am using jsp page to insert some value but when the parameters get to the servelet the values received are null when I am using Post method but when Get method is used then it works fine.
   request.getParameter() is returning null value when post method is used but when get method is used it works fine and the values get inserted

anyone have idea how to fix this???

//Jsp Page

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="insert.css">
    <title>Database Update</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 class="main-header">Enter the Details</h1>
    <div class="fullbody">

    <form action="Insert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="text">
    <b>Stuid:</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="stuid" name="stuid" pattern=[0-9]{1,} title="can only have numeric value" required>
    <b>Student Name:</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="student name" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{1,45}" title="can only have alphabet and space" required>
    <b>Student Mobile no.:</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="student mobile no." name="stumob" pattern=[0-9]{10} title="10 digit number" required>
    <br>
    <b>Father's Name:</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Father's name" name="fname" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{1,45}" title="can only have alphabet and space" required>
    <b>Father's Mobile no.:</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="father's mobile no." name="fmob" pattern=[0-9]{10} title="10 digit number" required>
    <br>
    <b>Mother's Name:</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mother's name" name="mname" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{1,45}" title="can only have alphabet and space" required>
    <b>Gender:</b>
    <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" required> Male
    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender"> Female
    <b>Date of Birth:</b>
    <input type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dob" required>
    <b>Address:</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="address" name="addr" required>
    <br>
    <b>Programme:</b>
    <select name="programme">
      <option value="B.tech">B.tech</option>
      <option value="M.tech">M.tech</option>
      <option value="BBA">BBA</option>
      <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
    </select>
    <b>Branch Code:</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="branch code" name="branch" pattern=[A-Za-z]{3,6} title="can only have alphabet" required>
    <b>Year:</b>
    <select name="year">
      <option value="1st">1st</option>
      <option value="2nd">2nd</option>
      <option value="3rd">3rd</option>
      <option value="4th">4th</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <b>Photo Upload:</b>
    <input type="file" name="photo" required>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>


    //servlet

    package java_app1;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    public class Insert extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            String stuid=request.getParameter("stuid");
            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String stumob=request.getParameter("stumob");
            String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
            String fmob=request.getParameter("fmob");
            String mname=request.getParameter("mname");
            String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
            String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
            String addr=request.getParameter("addr");
            String programme=request.getParameter("programme");
            String branch=request.getParameter("branch");
            String year=request.getParameter("year");
            String photo=request.getParameter("photo");       

            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println(stuid);

            try{
                   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                   Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student","root","ankit");               
                   PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into student.stulog values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                   ps.setString(1,stuid);
                   ps.setString(2,fmob);
                   ps.setString(3,name);
                   ps.setString(4,stumob);
                   ps.setString(5,fname);
                   ps.setString(6,fmob);
                   ps.setString(7,mname);
                   ps.setString(8,gender);
                   ps.setString(9,dob);
                   ps.setString(10,addr);
                   ps.setString(11,programme);
                   ps.setString(12,year);
                   ps.setString(13,branch);
                   ps.setString(14,photo);
                   int rs=ps.executeUpdate(); 
                   if(rs!=0)
                   {
                       out.println("[SUCCESS] RECORDS INSERTED SCUCCESSFULLY");
                       RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/dashboard.jsp");  
                       rd.include(request, response); 
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       out.println("[FAILURE] RECORDS NOT INSERTED");
                       RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/dashboard.jsp");  
                       rd.include(request, response); 
                   }
            }catch (Exception e)
              {
                out.println("Error:"+e);  
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way it work fine for me

in jsp:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/binod" method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstName"/>
<input type="submit"  value="login"/>
</form>
```

in servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/binod")
public class Test extends HttpServlet{

   @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("your name is"+req.getParameter("firstName"));

    }
}
```

You must `override` `doPost` method from `HttpServlet`

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
import

```
javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
```

step 2:
add annotation

```
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)    //Length of the file
```

after webServlet,urlPatterns

That's it !!

Answer (score -2):

add annotation to the servlet `@MultipartConfig`